# Is it possible to use Spark SQL with relational databases when the tables are big?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I want to know how can we use spark SQL to process structured big data stored in relational DB? I have tables that contain more than 4 billion lines (GPS coordinates). On using Merge operation, Spark tries to process the whole tables in the memory which is impossible. I know that Spark is "in-memory" processing, but in my case the memory can't fit for the whole tables. So is it possible to use spark with relational databases when the tables are big?

Answer (score 2):

In case the data to be read is more than the memory size, Spark does not cache the whole dataset into the memory all at once. The Spark documents states :

[Spark RDD Persistence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

> One of the most important capabilities in Spark is persisting (or caching) a dataset in memory across operations. When you persist an RDD, each node stores any partitions of it that it computes in memory and reuses them in other actions on that dataset

Also, one can provide Storage Level as **MEMORY_AND_DISK**

> **MEMORY_AND_DISK** : Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If the RDD does not fit in memory, store the partitions that don't fit on disk, and read them from there when they're needed.

Any of the Spark Data Structure you use, internally uses RDD.

Also assuming you are using JDBC to connect to external Database, you can specify the property **fetchsize** and **batchsize**

> **fetchsize** :The JDBC fetch size, which determines how many rows to fetch per round trip. This can help performance on JDBC drivers which default to low fetch size (eg. Oracle with 10 rows). This option applies only to reading.
>
> **batchsize** : The JDBC batch size, which determines how many rows to insert per round trip. This can help performance on JDBC drivers. This option applies only to writing. It defaults to 1000.

[JDBC To Other Databases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .option("fetchsize", "100")
  .load()
```